# Visualforce design

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I created a visualforce, but no change reflects on the page.

I'm using the lightning design system and I took this as an example:

DIV in lightning design system:

[image]

On my visualforce page:

[image]

This is a simple example of text size but nothing seems to reflect.

My visualforce Code:

[image]

What do I need to do to reflect the changes?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please include your code in the body of your question as text, not an image. Use the `{}` tool in tht editor to format it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<apex:slds />` to your page and wrap your code in a container:

`<div class="slds-scope">...</div>`

Refer to the documentation [here](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/).

Try to make changes according to the following. Please post a question with code rather than images next time. :)

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true" showHeader="false">
    <head>
        <apex:slds />
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.lightningStuff, 'salesforce-lightning-design-system.min')}"/>
    </head>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="slds-scope">
                <div class="slds-text-heading_large">
                    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```